# Why Dump operator return a path?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a simple pig code :

```
CRE_28001 = LOAD '$input' USING  PigStorage(';') AS (CIA_CD_CRV_CIA:chararray,CIA_DA_EM_CRV:chararray,CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE:chararray);  

-- Generer les colonnes du fichier

Data  = FOREACH CRE_28001 GENERATE
(chararray) CIA_CD_CRV_CIA AS CIA_CD_CRV_CIA,
(chararray) CIA_DA_EM_CRV AS CIA_DA_EM_CRV,
(chararray) CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE AS CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE,
(chararray) RUB_202 AS RUB_202;

-- Etablir le filtre exigee

CRE_28001_FILTER = FILTER Data BY (RUB_202 == '6');

LIMIT_DATA = LIMIT CRE_28001_FILTER 10;
DUMP LIMIT_DATA;
```

I am sure that my filter is correct. The column RUB_202 has over than 100 lines having '6' as a value. I verified that many times

Look what I get :

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 444 records (583792 bytes) from: "/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/BB0/MGM28001-2019-08-19.csv"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs://ha-manny/hdfs/hadoop/pig/tmp/temp1618713487/tmp-1281522727"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1549794175705_3500029       ->      job_1549794175705_3500031,
job_1549794175705_3500031
```

Note that I didn't demand to save the data in `hdfs://ha-manny/hdfs/hadoop/pig/tmp/temp1618713487/tmp-1281522727.`

Why this was automatically generated and I can see any data description or presentation.

I get that also when I just look to see the resukt of the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to reference columns using their index number instead of names.
In other words :

```
Data  = FOREACH CRE_28001 GENERATE
(chararray) $0 AS CIA_CD_CRV_CIA,
(chararray) $1 AS CIA_DA_EM_CRV,
(chararray) $2 AS CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE,
(chararray) $3 AS RUB_202;
```

Then I used the **TRIM** operator , because there was some columns wich has empty spaces in data !
And it works